# How can I split webpack generated JS to multiple files?

Tags: webpack

Previously, the site I've inherited has had all JS code exported to a single file which is used on all pages.

I've added a new page that would benefit from only having the JS for that specific page loaded when that page is the current one, so I want to split that out to a separate JS file.

Our current **webpack.config.js** contained this:

```
var loaders = [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['babel'],
    include: __dirname
  }
]

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    admin: './source/admin.js',
    main: '/source/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'js/main.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'production.new'),
    publicPath: '/production/'
  },
  module: {loaders: loaders}
};
```

I've never had to write a webpack config file before so after some poking around their documentation I tried adding this, but it didn't have the desired effect:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    admin: './source/admin.js',
    main: '/source/index.js',
    newpage: '/source/newpage.js'
  },
  // ...
  // Truncated to remove config as above
  // ...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  } 
};
```

What I want is two .js files to be outputted: **main.js** and **newpage.js**. What's happening is that the contents of **/source/newpage.js** are just being appended to the end of **main.js**.

How can I make webpack output those as two separate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less my proposal,
import './admin' into index.js file, it will solve your problem.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './source/index.js', // also includes admin.js
    newpage: './source/newpage.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js'
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all'
        },
      }
    },
  }
}
```